# Is there a way to programmatically move and resize gnome windows?

Tags: gnome

I'd like to get some of the functional of xmonad in gnome. Is it possible to write a shell script that will resize and position the windows that are open on the Gnome desktop?

Comment: **Devil's pie** comes to mind. See here:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/53935/how-to-make-programs-that-autostart-at-login-start-hidden/53968#53968

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do scripts using xdotool.

"**What is [xdotool](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xdotool)?**
This tool lets you simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc. It does this using X11's XTEST extension and other Xlib functions."

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `wmctrl`, that works with any EWMH/NetWM compatible window manager